# urlencode() not encoding inside value attribute

Tags: php, html

I know that urlencoding is used for url's but in the case I need to use it for a post value.

The problem that I am having is when I try encoding it inside the value attribute it doesn't do the encoding.

But when I encode the variable outside the value attribute and then just use the variable it works.

I am really confused on why that's working but when I use urlencoding in the value attribute its not working.

Here is my code. Any help would be really appreciated.

**Not encoding**

```
 <input type="hidden" name="proj" value="<?php echo urlencode($encrypted_params); ?>">
```

**Encoding** 
urlencoding($encrypted_params);

```
 <input type="hidden" name="proj" value="<?php echo $encrypted_params; ?>">
```

Comment: i suspect it is encoding, but depending on how you view it, you may not see it -demo show it is working = http://ideone.com/0epgFx

Comment: Surely you should be using htmlspecialchars?

Comment: @Dagon . Thank you for showing me a working example. It works now

Comment: i bet it was always working :-)